# using head(1) on dataframe causing timeout exception in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am running a simple spark-scala code :-

```
val df=spark.read.json("/home/files/data/date_20200811.json")
df.persist
if(!df.head(1).isEmpty){
val validDF=df.where("status=OLD")
validDF.write.json("/home/files/result")
}
else{
println("No data found")
}
```

When i am running this code it gives me an exception:-

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [300 seconds]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
        at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:107)
        at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
        at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:107)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoin.doExecute(BroadcastHashJoin.scala:107)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:132)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:130)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:130)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Project.doExecute(basicOperators.scala:46)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:132)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:130)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:130)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation.buildBuffers(InMemoryColumnarTableScan.scala:100)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation.<init>(InMemoryColumnarTableScan.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.InMemoryRelation$.apply(InMemoryColumnarTableScan.scala:41)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CacheManager$$anonfun$cacheQuery$1.apply(CacheManager.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CacheManager.writeLock(CacheManager.scala:60)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CacheManager.cacheQuery(CacheManager.scala:84)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.persist(DataFrame.scala:1596)
```

But if i replace **df.head(1).isEmpty**  with **df.count>0**. It work perfectly

Comment: isEmpty is a method, you have to invoke it, like this: !df.head(1).isEmpty()

Comment: In scala isEmpty() and isEmpty both will invoke this method, because it is an method without argument so () can be skipped @AdamDukkon

Comment: Could be a coincidence, are you sure this peice of code is the culprit behind the error? I think something is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a coincidence, are you sure this piece of code is the culprit behind the error? I think something is missing.

Please read line no 7 of your error `stacktrace`, it is `at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashJoin.doExecute(BroadcastHashJoin.scala:107)`.

This means somewhere a dataframe was broadcast for a join. And this broadcast did not complete in 300 seconds which is default `spark.sql.broadcastTimeout`.

Comment: I am not sure whether this  piece of code causing the error or not but after changing from head to count seems to resolve it....but don't know why...even if broadcast is happening then why it not giving same error if i use count instead of head.